# The drop down value is not inserted into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In this code i got undefined index:category in this i get the values from table name coursemaster col(course_code)now when i click upload the dropdown value is not inserted into student_table. So any one help me.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
             <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <head>
              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
              <title>Code Igniter</title>

                </head>

               <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
                <?php include_once('menu.php'); ?>
                <br />

                <div class="gray_bg">
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row welcome_inner">
                 <div class="span12">
                <h1><span class="colored">///</span> Upload</h1>
            </div>
             </div>
              </div>
              </div>
          <div id="details">
              </div></div></center>
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

         File to import:<br />

         <input size='30' type='file' name='filename'>

          Enter subject code:<input type="text" name="fname1" />
          Enter subject code:<input type="text" name="fname2" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"></form>




          <?php 
         $host="localhost";
         $username="root";
          $password="";
         $db_name="slseatapp"; 

          mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
         mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select db");
         $query="SELECT id,course_code FROM `coursemaster` ORDER BY `coursemaster`.`id`";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
           ?>

          <select name="category">
          <?php
          while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo '<option value="'.$nt['course_code'].'">'.$nt['course_code'].'</option>';
           }
           ?>
           </select>



          <?php

         if($_POST){
          echo 'The course_code selected is'.$_POST['category'];
                }
          ?>



         <?php 

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

           mysql_select_db("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

          //Upload File 
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
      if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) { 


     //Import uploaded file to Database 
           $row = 1; 
         $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r"); 
       $var = $_POST['category'];
       $var1 = $_POST['fname1'];
        $var2 = $_POST['fname2'];



         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 

          //Update Database Values 

              $import="insert into student_table (id,register_number,name,course_code,subject_code,exam_name) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$var','$var1','$var2')"; 
            $import="replace into  student_table (id,register_number,name,course_code,subject_code,exam_name) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$var','$var1','$var2')";


              mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error()); 


              } 



           fclose($handle); 
        echo"uploaded successfully";
            }
           } 
          ?>
<br />
     <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
       </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your HTML is not perfect, try this

```
<select name="category">
              <?php
              while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
              echo '<option value="'.$nt['course_code'].'">'.$nt['course_code'].'</option>';
               }
               ?>
               </select>
```

Comment: It shows undefined index:category on line 63 and 81 the dropdown selected values are not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

firsly you have miss `"` around name of select try to change this:

```
<select name=category>
<?php
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$nt['course_code']."'>".$nt['course_code']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

to this:

```
<select name="category">
<?php
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$nt['course_code']."'>".$nt['course_code']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

You have too many forms, and you want to update all in ne.
You should use only one form and only one submit button to upload all your values try to use only one form and only one submit for all your values. You have a form for the inout type file and a form for the select category, you should use only one for each other.

Try

Comment: undefined index category in line 63 and 81 and makes course code column empty in student_table.

Comment: See my update use pnly one form please and try again, bevause I think you click in the first submit button, but if you click in the second error is in the file that you want to uplad.. use only one form please   @moses